# sparql wikidata - how to only show statements without any references

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to gather all statements for a specific topic (let's say Václav Havel - Q36233) but I need to exclude all statements that include any reference.

```
SELECT ?subjectLabel ?property ?object ?objectLabel
    WHERE {
      ?subject ?property ?object.
      FILTER (?subject = wd:Q36233)
      FILTER(REGEX(STR(?property), "http://www.wikidata.org/prop/.*"))
      FILTER(REGEX(STR(?object), "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q.*"))
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

This query results in 194 statements but among those are statements that also include references.

I need the result list to include this:
[0 references = show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3GbC.png)

But not include this:
[1+ references = not show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYEIF.png)

I tried many ways of changing the query by adding MINUS operator and FILTER operator, but none of those worked and usually resulted in 0 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?subjectLabel ?property ?object ?objectLabel
WHERE {
  ?subject ?property ?object .
  ?subject ?p ?stmt.
  ?stmt ?ps ?object .
  
  BIND (URI(REPLACE(STR(?p),STR(p:),STR(wdt:))) as ?property)
  BIND (URI(REPLACE(STR(?p),STR(p:),STR(ps:))) as ?ps)
  
  FILTER (?subject = wd:Q36233)
  FILTER (REGEX(STR(?p), STR(p:)))
  FILTER (REGEX(STR(?object), STR(wd:)))
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?stmt prov:wasDerivedFrom ?ref . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

where `FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?stmt prov:wasDerivedFrom ?ref . }` is checking that the statement `?stmt` does not have a references.

Note that `?subject ?p ?stmt. ?stmt ?ps ?object .` is almost equivalent to `?subject ?property ?object .`, except that the `wdt:` prefix searches for best statement (for example excluding deprecated ones), while the `p:` prefix does not. Thus `?subject ?property ?object .` is not redundant because in general you cannot safely remove it.

A more efficient version using [Blazergraph's QueryHints](https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/QueryHints):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?subjectLabel ?property ?object ?objectLabel
WHERE {
  ?subject ?property ?object .
  {
    SELECT ?subject ?p ?stmt ?object (URI(REPLACE(STR(?p),STR(p:),STR(wdt:))) as ?property)
    WHERE {
      ?subject ?p ?stmt.
      ?stmt ?ps ?object .
      BIND (URI(REPLACE(STR(?p),STR(p:),STR(ps:))) as ?ps)
      FILTER (?subject = wd:Q36233)
      FILTER (REGEX(STR(?p), STR(p:)))
      FILTER (REGEX(STR(?object), STR(wd:)))
      hint:SubQuery hint:runOnce true .
    }
  }
  hint:Prior hint:runFirst true .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?stmt prov:wasDerivedFrom ?ref . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much. It seems like 100 % of the results are now without any references, but for some reason some of the statements are missing. For example, when changing topic to Donald Trump (Q22686) it returns statement [Donald Trump - residence - Mar-a-Lago] but fortgets about [Donald Trump - residence - Trump Tower] which I manually checked for and also has 0 references.

Nevertheless thank you very much for your previous answer! I will try to take a look at this little problem:)

Comment: This is because Mar-a-Lago (Q1262898) is currently set as preferred value for the property P551. As I partially explained, if you want to consider all the possible statements (maybe including deprecated ones), then you have to use `p:` instead of `wdt:` (see [Help:Ranking § How to query and filter among ranks](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Ranking#How_to_query_and_filter_among_ranks)). In case, just tell me and I will edit the answer.

Comment: So do I use another BIND function as you use? I understand that I have to use the prefix p: instead of wdt: but do not know how to replace it and for which property variable (?property, ?p or ?ps). And I checked the link you sent but they use specific properties (p: and some specific number).

Comment: You can just remove `?subject ?property ?object .`, that I used for binding subjects and objecto with a `wdt:` property.

Comment: Then, if you are ok that `p:` values are returned as output instead of `wdt:` ones, you may also want to get rid of the `?property` variable in the `SELECT` statements and just use `?p` (then obviously rename them as you wish).

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I am very grateful for your help!
Is there any way to recommend you besides accepting your answer? I do not use stackoverflow very often so I do not know the options.

Comment: Users with 15 reputation can [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answers :-)